# .env file not being recognized when trying to read from a file within a folder instead of root in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, dotenv

In my NodeJS app, I have .env file in root directory with following info:

```
NODE_ENV = development
PORT = 3002
#db credentials
dbURL = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@clusterName-0gcm3.mongodb.net/dbName?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

And in the root directory I also have config file (config.js) which grabs the variables:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
  port: process.env.PORT,
  dbURL: process.env.dbURL
}
```

In my App.js which is again in root folder I am able to successfully read this file and able to connect with DB:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { port, dbURL } = require('./config');  //reading the config file and grabbing the vars
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

//works well!
mongoose.connect(dbURL, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true})
        .then(res => {
          console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
          app.listen(port);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Now I am trying to write some standalone scripts to populate the DB with some sample data and in that script I am trying to connect to DB seperately as those scripts will only be executed with `node <file>` command. This file (dbPopulate.js) is located within /helper-scripts/ folder. And the script looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {port, dbURL} = require('../config'); //attempting to read config.js that calls the .env file

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());


console.log(dbURL, port) //throws undefined for both vars
mongoose.connect(dbURL, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true})
        .then(res => {
          console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
          app.listen(port);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Just to make it clear this is my file structure:

```
/.env
/app.js
/config.js
/helper-scripts/dbPopulate.js  (culprit)
```

UPDATE for displaying error log:

When I execute dbPopulate.js standalone I get following errors:

```
$ node dbPopulate.js
undefined undefined
C:\teamSIO\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:582
    throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
    ^

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\teamSIO\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:582:11)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\teamSIO\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:335:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\teamSIO\server\helper-scripts\dbPopulate.js:30:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1123:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:872:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the deconstructing? 
`const {port, dbURL} = require('../config');`  Have you tried exporting a single config function from that file and within the function set `dotenv.config();` and return a config object containing ur port and dburl

Comment: Im not able to follow. Could you please explain with a code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

when u run a node app where the .env file is not in the same relative location as the file u are running then u need to specify the correct path for the .env file.
Example if i have app.js and .env file both inside the same project folder location then when I'll do node app.js, then just dotenv.config() will work fine as its default path is

```
process.cwd() + '.env'
```

but for say i have a file inside seeder/chat-message-type.seeder.js then to read the .env file which is outside i have to go out one directory.

```
const path = require("path")

// have to modify dotenv file path becuase the app is run from seeder folder
dotenv.config({ path: path.join(process.cwd(), "..", ".env") })
```

This will ensure that whenever i am reading the .env file by running

```
cd seeder
node chat-message-type.seeder.js
```

it will still load all the data from .env file.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using an array instead of an object.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const port = process.env.PORT;
dbURL: process.env.dbURL;
module.exports = [
    port,
    dbURL
];
```

and to use

```
const [port, dbURL] = require('./config');
```

Also, I don't think that this was the error, but you do have two dots in your "dbPopulate.js" `const {port, dbURL} = require('../config');` file, this might be your problem

Comment: Thanks @Daniel.  But I am not sure why 2 dots are a problem because my config file is up one level so it wont be accessible with a single dot. Is this different when dealing with .env files? Also is there a reason for using array instead of object? Note that this is working correctly when using in app.js. Only in non-root file dbPopulate.js I am facing this problem

Comment: I tried your solution but it has no effect. I am still having the same problem. I dont think object destructuring is the issue here. Because if that was the case it wouldn't have worked for root level scenario as well.

Comment: When you run JUST the dbPopulate script are you getting an error? or is it only when app is running. (it appears that you are using the same port and this could become a problem) can you post what the error logs are?

Comment: when app.js runs everything is fine as I noticed both config.js and app.js are at the root level. But when I try to execute dbPopulate standalone it doesn't work. I will update the stacktrace in the question due to char limit here.

Comment: try being in the root directory and calling: ```node ./helper-scripts/dbPopulate```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since you asked, but maybe my answer will help someone else.

When you execute `node dbPopulate.js` from directory `helper-scripts` the function `require` will be able to correctly load `../config`, but that in turn will fail to find the file `.env` because it expects to find it at the same level, from a file/directory hierarchy perspective.

You can either copy `.env` inside `helper-scripts`, which you'd better not, or execute `dbPopulate.js` from project's root directory.